# How to find XML on webpages

Tags: xml, screen-scraping, html

For the following webpage:
http://www.realclearpolitics.com/epolls/2012/president/us/general_election_romney_vs_obama-1171.html

How would I go about finding the XML associated with the data in the chart. I know that the XML page is http://charts.realclearpolitics.com/charts/1171.xml because someone told me. But how would i figure this out on my own?

Thanks

Comment: There is no rule that says that every content generated from XML needs to make the XML publicly available as well.

Comment: American politics - the three Gs - Guns Gays and God!. Seems quite clear

Answer (score 0):

Usually you can find an rss link on the website or view the page source and search for .xml

You can also use the following query on google:

**site:realclearpolitics.com filetype:xml**

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the following linq xml?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;


namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("http://charts.realclearpolitics.com/charts/1171.xml");

        }
    }
}
​
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it to plot

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.IO;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("http://charts.realclearpolitics.com/charts/1171.xml");
            var results = new {
                X = doc.Descendants("series").Descendants("value").Select(y => (DateTime)y).ToList(),
                Obama = doc.Descendants("graph").Where(y => y.Attribute("title").Value == "Obama").Descendants("value").Select(y => (string)y == "" ?null : (double?)y).ToList(),
                Romney = doc.Descendants("graph").Where(y => y.Attribute("title").Value == "Romney").Descendants("value").Select(y => (string)y == "" ?null : (double?)y).ToList()
            };


            chart1.Series.Add("Obama");
            chart1.Series["Obama"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Point;
            chart1.Series["Obama"].Points.DataBindXY(results.X, results.Obama);
             chart1.Series.Add("Romney");
            chart1.Series["Romney"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Point;
            chart1.Series["Romney"].Points.DataBindXY(results.X, results.Romney);
            chart1.DataBind();

        }
    }
}
​
```